# Associative quick find of NSDictionary as elements of NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

Suppose I have an NSMutableArray of NSDictionary like this (every row is a dictionary):

```
     key count type
 0    1   1     Apple
 1    1   2     Banana
 2    2   1     Pear
 3    3   4     Ananas
```

Suppose that I would find all fruits for key 1. The simple and brute way is enumerate the NSMutableArray and find only those NSDictionary  which have as key = 1.
There is a better or smarter way?
(Data come from an SQL query).

Comment: i am putting only one value you just need to put all you wanted value here..

Comment: using `key` as a name for a dictionary's key __might__ cause you problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method of `NSArray`:

```
// Supposing originalArray is an NSArray holding the NSDictionaries that represent the fruits
NSArray *filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key == %@", @1]];
```

`filteredArray` will now hold all the dictionaries with `1` as key.

Comment: Thanks. I did even know of filtering capability of NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"1" forKey:@"YourKey"]];
    NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(YourKey == %@)", @"1"]];

    NSLog(@"%@",filtered);
```

Try this one might be helpful to you..